# OnCreate of Application class is not called in Android 6

Tags: android, oncreate

I have an Application class, but the OnCreate method is not called on my HTC One m8 **(Android 6)**. On the emulator **(Android 5.1)** it works fine.

```
public class App extends Application {

private static Context context;

@Override 
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    context = getApplicationContext();
}

public static Context getContext(){
    return context;
}

}
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<application
    android:name=".App"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: any errors shows in logs?

Comment: No it does not give any errors. It gives a NullPointerException when the App.getContext() method is called.

Comment: code is fine how are you calling `getContext()` show that code.

Comment: How do you know `onCreate()` is not called?

Comment: @Abbas since somewhere in his code `getContext()` on application class is coming out null

Comment: I placed breakpoints and it never gets called.

Comment: @tomhogenkamp Code looks fine. Can you check again with a fully qualified class name in manifest?

Comment: I have a Nexus 7 running 6.0.1 and your code, I added a Log message in the `onCreate()`. Seems to be an issue specific to one device. Try getting another device running 6.

Answer (score 1):

Just check with App class is placed in correct place. If you set name with .APP then it will look that class in com.yourpackage.APP else place correct path in manifest.  If all fine then sure onCreate will be called and getApplicationContext() will give context reference.